# Update data in MongoDB with Mongojs using findAndModify()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Yet another first-timer problem here. This gets data from a database and displays it in some text fields (that part is not shown in the code below) and after the user edits it the data should be updated in the database via the findAndModify() method and I think this is where the issue lies. There are no errors, it just doesn't do anything. **EDIT** The following error is received: *MongoError: Either an update or remove=true must be specified*

**server.js**

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://user:secretPassword@aws-us-east-1-portal.7.dblayer.com:10712,aws-us-east-1-portal.10.dblayer.com:10316/database", function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var contactList = db.collection("contactList");

app.put('/contactList/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("edited: " + req.body.name); //works up until here
    contactList.findAndModify({
        query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
        update: {$set: {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, number: req.body.number}},
        new: true
    }, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    })
});
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.update = function() {
    $http.put('/contactList/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
        refresh();
    })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were me I would first do a couple of things:

1. Before your call to findAndModify just do a simple find using your query.  Make sure you can actually find the object using your query.  If that works you know that the 'find' part of the findAndModify is probably ok.
2. Do some console logging inside the callback handler of the findAndModify call.  As it stands you do not do anything if an err is returned from the findAndModify call.  It is possible your call is returning an error that you are just ignoring and it may provide some additional insight into your problem.

I would try these two first and see if it helps.

Update:

Example using native:

```
collection.findAndModify(
     { field: 'some value' }, 
     [], 
     { $set: { field2: 'some new value' } }, 
     { new:true }, 
     function(err, doc) {
        //handle err and doc
     });
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I get the following error after changing the callback handler, "MongoError: Either an update or remove=true must be specified". Are they not already specified in the code I posted above?

Comment: What is "MongoClient" here?  My guess is you may need to use the native driver syntax if that is what you have a handle to.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure that was the Mongo URI connection string provided by Compose.io

Comment: No, I mean what literally is "MongoClient" here.  There has to be a require up higher that creates it.  I'm trying to see what specific mongo driver you are using.

Comment: Gotcha, it's mongodb. I think I see the problem.

Comment: You have to use the native driver differently.  I'll edit my answer to show you an example